# AWS Rekognition Custom Labels Training "The manifest file contains too many invalid data objects" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to do a quick PoC on the AWS Rekognition custom labels feature.  I'd like to try using it for object detection.

I've had a couple of attempts at setting it up using only tools in the AWS Console. I'm using images imported from the Rekognition bucket in S3, then I added bounding boxes using the tools in the Rekognition console.

All of my images are marked up with bounding boxes, no whole image labels have been used. I have 9 labels, all of which appear in at least 1 drawing.

I've ensured my images are less than 4096x4096 in size (which is mentioned [on this AWS forums thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=952624&#952624) as a possible cause of this issue.

When I attempt to train my model I get the "The manifest file contains too many invalid data objects" error.

What could be wrong here?  An error message complaining about the format of a file I didn't create manually, that I can't see or edit isn't exactly intuitive.

Comment: Maybe the objects you have listed in the manifest file have an incorrect path? It might also be that it can only reference S3 buckets in the same region as Rekognition is being used.

Comment: The S3 bucket is in the same region as I'm trialing Rekognition in (it's the S3 bucket created by Rekognition, so wouldn't expect any access/policy issues).  Having found the manifest in that bucket now, the file path does seem to be correct.  The Rekognition tooling in the console had no problems accessing the files to let me add the bounding boxes.

Comment: Maybe try halving the number of objects in the manifest to see if the error goes away? Or, it might help identify if any references are invalid.